# How do I make a working score function that removes an item and then adds score, while removing its old number from the test area

Tags: javascript, counter, collision-detection

I'm trying to make snake using a gridbased system where I move a set amount each time I press the arrow keys. I'm having issues with collisions and points, where the controlled square (the snake) removes the point square (the apple) in the bottom left is the points being displayed,

```
function scoreFunc(){ scoreText = new Text(score); scoreText.setPosition(H_G_SIZE, getHeight()-H_G_SIZE); scoreText.setText(score); add(scoreText); }

function movement(e){ if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){ snake.move(-MOVE_XDISTANCE, 0); }

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
    snake.move(MOVE_XDISTANCE, 0);
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
    snake.move(0, -MOVE_YDISTANCE);
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
    snake.move(0, MOVE_YDISTANCE);
}

if(snake.getX() < apple.getX() + apple.getWidth()
&& 
    snake.getX() + snake.getWidth() > apple.getX() 
    &&
    snake.getY() < apple.getY() + apple.getHeight()
    &&
    snake.getY() + snake.getHeight() > apple.getY()){
        var score = 0;
        remove(apple);
        score++;
        return score; //i don't know what im doing    
    }
}

start(){ snake = new Rectangle(SNAKE_XSIZE, SNAKE_YSIZE); snake.setPosition(MARGIN_GAP+GUIDELINE_SIZE, MARGIN_GAP+GUIDELINE_SIZE); snake.setColor("#19801d"); add(snake); keyDownMethod(movement); scoreFunc(); //setTimer(scoreFunc, 100);
```

it is supposed to remove the apple, and add a point to the score when the snake moves over the apple, eventually it's supposed to add a snake segment behind it but I'm running out of time before school ends. what it actually does is remove the apple visibly, leaving the part that adds points behind, the score also doesn't delete and overlaps on itself, (hence the commented out set timer). if anyone could help me figure it out it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

many problems with the code, but here's a few things to think about:

1. If statements do not have "return". `return score;` does not make sense and probably should be part of a function.
2. In order to detect collision, you need to loop through an array of apples. your code seems to have 1 snake and 1 apple, but that doesn't make much sense.
3. There are better ways to detect collision in javascript than what you are doing.
4. You should have a moveSnake function and a detectCollision function. keep them separate and do them one at a time.

good luck!